# MongoDB Pagination with two values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Let's say my MongoDB records look like this:

1. {category: A , sub_category : 1}
2. {category: A , sub_category : 2}
3. {category: A , sub_category : 3}
4. {category: B , sub_category : 1}
5. {category: B , sub_category : 2}
6. {category: B , sub_category : 3}
7. {category: C , sub_category : 1}
8. {category: C , sub_category : 2}
9. {category: C , sub_category : 3}

I am trying to achieve pagination with these values. So, I created a compound index with both of these fields (both in ascending order).

Let's say my page limit is 2.

So my first query looks like this -> db.record.find().sort({category: 1, sub_category: 1}); -> And the first two records are returned.

My second query looks like this -> db.record.find({category : {$gte: A}, sub_category: {$gt : 2}}).sort({category: 1, sub_category: 1}).

I was expecting record 3 and 4 to return. But I got record 3 and record 6.

I understood that my way of querying is not right. I couldn't find another solution. Please help me with this issue.

P.S. I am not using skip and limit technique, because I am following [bucket pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1).

Comment: In your second query, you are passing where clause for the query so the data is returning correctly 3 and 6 because 4th and 5th records subcategory values are not greater than 2.
For pagination, you need to use skip and limit functions

Comment: like for the second page, your query will be db.record.find().skip(2).limit(2)

Comment: @AdnanAhmedAnsari Hi Adnan. Thanks for your response. Actually, we should not use skip and limit functions for pagination. Please have a look at this link https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1

Comment: Then you should change your query to db.record.find({ $or: [ { category : 'A' , sub_category:  {$gt : 2}}, { category : {$gt: 'A'} } ] })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the suggestions from Tom Slabbaert and Adnan Ahmed Ansari, and the solution worked.

I used this query:

```
db.record.find({ $or: [ { category : 'A' , sub_category: {$gt : 2}}, { category : {$gt: 'A'} } ] })
```

Answer (score 0):

When querying in Mongo if the query can be satisfied by an index then Mongo will traverse the index trees (B-tree's) and will not perform collection scan.

So the expected documents order is basically just a "perceived order". the documents "index order" is different and heavily relies on what fields were indexed, document insertion order and more.

So what can you do? you can force your perceived order by using `sort`:

```
db.record.find({category : {$gte: A}, sub_category: {$gt : 2}}).sort({category: 1, sub_category: 1});
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for the response. Actually, I am using the sort feature as well. I forgot to add it in the question. Sorry about that

Comment: Well specifically here you use `sub_category: {$gt : 2}` so documents 4 and 5 get thrown out due to that condition.

Comment: You should use `{
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        {category : A},
                        {sub_category: {$gt : 2}}
                    ]
                },
                {category : {$gt: A}},
            ]
        }` query to follow your rules.

Comment: Yeah. I follow this technique, and it worked. Thanks for your time Tom :)

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Can You Please Help Me In Paginating With More Than 2 Field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163444/how-can-paginate-on-mongodb-with-more-than-2-field