# How Can Paginate On Mongodb With More Than 2 Field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination, mongodb-query, nosql

How Can Paginate On Mongodb With More Than 2 Field
My Data Looks like this {_id,product_name,price,rating,search_score}
To Paginate Next Page With 2 Sort Field (Price , _id) , I Am Using This Logic

```
db.users.find({
   $or: [
     { price: { $gt: 99 } },
     {
       price: 99,
       _id: { $gt: ObjectId("5f7f1f7d67f67ddaa622b796") }
     }
   ]
 }).sort({
   price: 1,
   _id: 1
 }).limit(3).pretty()
```

So Now I Want To Sort More Than 2  Field That Is (Price,rating,_id) 3 Field Or Else 4 Field With (Price,rating,search_score,_id,) And I Have Compound Index For (Price,rating,_id) And Also For  (Price,rating,search_score,_id,) But I Am Bit Confused In DB Query  And  I Would Be Thankful If You Can Help Me Out :)